# Find 2 sums with the binomial newton

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

Find the sum of:

i)$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2$ $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$

ii) $\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2k+5}{k+1}$$\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$

---

Thoughts:

i)(After the Edit)$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} k^2$ $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$ =
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} {k(k-1)}$ $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$ + $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k}$ $\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$=
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n(k-1)}$ $\left(\begin{array}{c} n-1\\k-1\end{array}\right)$ + $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}{n}$ $\left(\begin{array}{c} n-1\\k-1\end{array}\right)$=
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n} {n(n-1)}$ $\left(\begin{array}{c} n-2\\k-2\end{array}\right)$ + n$\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n}$ $\left(\begin{array}{c} n-1\\k-1\end{array}\right)$=
$n(n-1)2^{n-2}+n2^{n-1}$=$n2^{n-2}(2+n-1)$=$n(n+1)2^{n-2}$

ii)(After the Edit)$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{2k+5}{k+1}$$\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$=
$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{(2k+2)+3}{k+1}$$\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$=
2$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}$$\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$ + 3$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k+1}$$\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$=

$2^{n+1}-2$+ $\frac{3}{n+1}$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{n+1}{k+1}$$\left(\begin{array}{c} n\\k\end{array}\right)$=
$2^{n+1}-2$+ $\frac{3}{n+1}$$\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{n}$$\left(\begin{array}{c} n+1\\k+1\end{array}\right)$=
$2^{n+1}-2+\frac{3}{n+1}(2^{n+1}-1)$

Comment: Hint on the first one: $\sum_{k=0}^n k^2 {n \choose k}=\sum_{k=0}^n k(k-1) {n \choose k} + \sum_{k=0}^n k {n \choose k}$. This trick ensures that you always have the right term in the denominator available to cancel with. This trick is usually the way you want to approach these types of problems (in particular I imagine some variant of it will help in your other problems).

Comment: Also, +1 for well-organized attempts that are actually on the right track.

Comment: Hello Ian. Can you see my solution,I think is correct?

Comment: You can find something about the first identity in [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231596/induction-sum-k-0n-binom-nk-k2-n1n2n-2) and other posts [linked there](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/231596).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

ii) We can expand as follows
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+5}{k+1}{n\choose k}&=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k+2)+3}{k+1}{n\choose k}\\[4pt]
&=\sum_{k=1}^n 2{n\choose k}+\frac{3}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n+1}{k+1}{n\choose k}\\[4pt]
&=2\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}+\frac{3}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n{{n+1}\choose {k+1}}
\end{align*}

---

Notice $$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}=2^n\qquad\implies\qquad\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}=2^n-1,$$
then,
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+5}{k+1}{n\choose k}&=2\sum_{k=1}^n{n\choose k}+\frac{3}{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n{{n+1}\choose {k+1}}=2(2^n-1)+\frac{3}{n+1}(2^{n+1}-1)
\end{align*}
Which can be reduced as
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{2k+5}{k+1}{n\choose k}=\frac{2^{n+1}(n+4)-2n-5}{n+1}$$

Comment: Hello.Thank you for you hint.Please check my answer and tell me if its correct.Did I miss something?

Comment: @MarkoPolo There are two mistakes, see my last edition.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! I fully understand it right now!

Answer (score 2):

For the first one:

We know that:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k}x^k}={(1+x)}^{n}
$$

So let's differentiate it to get:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k{n\choose k}{x}^{k-1}}=n{(1+x)}^{n-1}
$$

Multiply by $x$ and differntiate again:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k^2{n\choose k}{x}^{k-1}}=(nx{(1+x)}^{n-1})'\\
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k^2{n\choose k}{x}^{k-1}}=n({(1+x)}^{n-1}+(n-1)x{(1+x)}^{n-2})\\
$$

Multiply by $x$ one more time to get:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k^2{n\choose k}{x}^{k}}=nx({(1+x)}^{n-1}+(n-1)x{(1+x)}^{n-2})\\
$$
 Now just put $x=1$ and you'll get the answer.

Let's move on to the next one:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{2k+5}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k} =2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{k}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k}+5\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k}\\
=2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{(1-\frac{1}{k+1}){n\choose k}x^k}+5\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k}\\
=2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k}x^k}-2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k}+5\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k}\\
=2{(1+x)}^{n}-2\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k}+5\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k}
$$

Now let's compute :

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k}
$$

We have:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k}x^k} = {(1+x)}^{n}
$$

Let's integrate to get:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}{x}^{k+1}}=\frac{{(1+x)}^{n+1}}{n+1}+C
$$

For $x=0$ the sum is $0$ so :

$$
C=-\frac{1}{n+1}
$$

We finally get:

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k}=\frac{1}{x}(\frac{{(1+x)}^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1})
$$

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{2k+5}{k+1}{n\choose k}x^k} = 2{(1+x)}^{n}-2(\frac{1}{x}(\frac{{(1+x)}^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}))+5(\frac{1}{x}(\frac{{(1+x)}^{n+1}}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}))
$$
Now plug in $x=1$ and you'll get the answer