# Finding $\sum_{_{0\le i}}\sum_{_{<j\le n}} {n \choose i}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, binomial-coefficients

Let
$$S=\sum_{0\le i}\sum_{<j\le n} {n \choose i}\tag{*}$$
Consider the summation:
$$\sum_{j=0}^{n}\sum_{i=0}^{n} A_i B_j=\sum_{i=0}^n A_i B_i+\sum_{0\le i<j\le n} A_i B_j+ \sum_{n\ge i>j\ge 0} A_i B_j$$
If $B_j=1$, then the second and the third sums in RHS above are  equal, then
$$\sum_{0\le i<j\le n}A_i=\frac{1}{2}\left[\sum_{j=0}^n\sum_{i=0}^{n} A_i-\sum_{i=0}^n A_i\right]=\frac{1}{2}\left[(n+1)\sum_{i=0}^nA_i-\sum_{i=0}^nA_i\right]$$
Finally, taking $A_i={n \choose i}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^{n} {n \choose i} =2^n$, we get $S=n2^{n-1}$.

The question is: How else this sum (*) can be evaluated?

**Edit:** It requires good steps to show that $S=\sum_{k=0}^{n} k {n \choose k}$
and hence this question cannot be taken as duplicate. See the positive comments of @jjagmath and @Phicar below.

Comment: Why is there $j$ in $(*)$?

Comment: @Aig  It is a restricted double summation. I have edited it now.

Comment: @ZAhmed Your notation was correct, so I reverted your edit.

Comment: Well, you can write your sum as $$\sum _{i = 0}^n\binom{n}{i}(n-i),$$
where the $n-i$ comes from all choises of $j$ given $i$. Just use that $\binom{n}{m}\binom{m}{k}=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{m-k}$.

Comment: @jjagmath  Thanks for the support and edit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute this combinatoric sum?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3083227/how-to-compute-this-combinatoric-sum) $$\sum_{i = 0}^n\binom{n}{i}(n-i)=\sum_{k= 0}^n\binom n k k$$ and there are [many post about this sum](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5Enk%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%24&p=1).

Comment: Is your question correct? Isnt it it supposed to be Double sigma 0<i<j<n nci ncj? I think your question is missing the ncj term

Comment: @Mathslover Please read the proof(S).

Comment: The fun is that the present proposal strikes interest, some even find it wrong or misprinted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sum is actually a double sum
$$S=\sum_{j=0}^{n} \sum_{i=0}^{j-1} {n \choose i}$$
This can be expanded as
$$S={n \choose 0}+\left[{n \choose 0}+{n \choose 1}\right]+\left[{n \choose 0}+{n\choose 1}+{n \choose 2}\right]+\left[{n \choose 0}+{n \choose 1}+{n \choose 2}+{n \choose 3}\right]+.......+[0]$$
This is as though the frequency of ${n \choose i}$ is $(n-i)$, then
$$=\sum_{i=0}^{n} (n-i) {n \choose i}=\sum_{k=0}^n k {n \choose k}=n 2^{n-1}$$

Comment: The main step (the previous ones were already noticed in comments) is the last equality, which (as also commented) is a [mega duplicate](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bk%3D0%7D%5Enk%5Cbinom%7Bn%7D%7Bk%7D%24&p=1).