# Proving Identity In Combinatorial and Algebraic Way

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I need to prove the identity $$\sum_{k = 0}^{n} k^2\binom{n}{k} = n(n - 1)2^{n - 2} + n2^{n - 1}$$ in two ways : in algebraic way and combinatorial way.

About the algebraic way - I tried to find a formula to be placed in the identity that could help me solve the problem but without success.
Combinatorial way - I couldn't find a "story" that is proof of identity.

Comment: Take a committee of $n$ people. A subcommittee is formed; it must have a chair and secretary, but they can be the same person.

Comment: In your summation, $n \choose k$ is the number of ways to pick a subset of size $k$ from a set of size $n$. You now have $k$ distinguished elements. Think about what the $k^2$ means in terms of these distinguished elements.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @JeremyDover so k^2 means number of ways to choose subsets?

Comment: For the algebraic route, one attack is to try an manipulate the binomial theorem $(1+x)^n=\dots$, taking derivatives and such to get the sum you want. Another is to write $k^2=k(k-1)+k$, split into two sums, and use the  [absorption identity](https://www.google.com/amp/s/mikespivey.wordpress.com/2012/12/10/absorption-identity/amp/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Induction: $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom nk k^2 = n(1+n)2^{n-2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/231596/induction-sum-k-0n-binom-nk-k2-n1n2n-2) (which has algebraic as well as combinatorial answers)

Comment: @ISR_Student: Check out Lord Shark's comment. There are $n \choose k$ ways to form the subcommittee. The $k^2$ corresponds to the chair and secretary.

Answer (score 0):

Algebraic way:
Consider the function $f(x)=(x+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{{n\choose k}}x^k$. Note that $f(1)=2^n$.

Now we differentiate twice:
$$f’(1)=n(1+1)^{n-1}= \sum_{k=1}^{n}{k{n\choose k}} $$ and $$f’’(1)=n(n-1)(1+1)^{n-2}= \sum_{k=2}^{n}{(k^2-k){n\choose k}}$$
$$= f’’(1)=n(n-1)2^{n-2}= \sum_{k=2}^{n}{k^2{n\choose k}}-\sum_{k=2}^{n}{k{n\choose k}}$$
$$n(n-1)2^{n-2}= \sum_{k=2}^{n}{k^2{n\choose k}}-f’(1)+n$$ 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: 'n' how to i get k from 0 to k in the sigma in the right side , it connects with 'n' that also in the right side of the final equation?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:
A combinatorial approach is mentioned in a comment. Here is a hint, try to use:

> $$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}$$