# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k}=n(n+1)2^{n-2}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k}=n(n+1)2^{n-2}$

I tried like this:

I used induction on $n$.
I took $n=2$ then $LHS= \sum_{k=1}^2 k^2\binom{n}{k}=1\times 2+4\times 1=6$
and $RHS=2(2+1)=6$

and so its verified.

Now we assume that $\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \binom{n}{k}=n(n+1)2^{n-2}$ is tue.
We prove it for $n+1$.

Now $\sum_{k=1}^{n+1} k^2 \binom{n+1}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^n k^2 \binom{n+1}{k}+(n+1)^2$.

I cant know  how to get $(n+2)(n+1)2^{n-1}$ from here.

Can someone please help me out?

I found an answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/231602/665065 which is the best and efficient. Thank you all for your effort

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use $\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$.

Comment: Thank you but how to tackle the term $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^2\binom{n}{k-1}$??

Comment: @Math_Freak:  write:  $k^2 = (k-1)^2 +2(k-1) + 1$

Comment: @Math_Freak: The one you have equals : $n2^{n-1}$ ( I think ).

Answer (score 0):

**Combinatorial Proof**

**Counting in method $1$:**
We count the number of committees formed out of $n$ people with one president and one vice president with the condition that both president and vice president can be the same person.
Number of such committees of size $k$ is $k^2\binom{n}{k}$(why?). So the total number of such committees is $\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2\binom{n}{k}$.

**Counting in method $2$:**
Now we chose a president first and a vice president and then the rest committee. When the president and vice president are the same then the number of such committees is $n2^{n-1}$(why?). When they are different people, the number is $n(n-1)2^{n-2}$(why?). So the total number of such committees is $n2^{n-1}+n(n-1)2^{n-2}=(2n+n(n-1))2^{n-1}=(2n+n^2-n)2^{n-1}=n(n+1)2^{n-1}$

Hence we get,
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}k^2\binom{n}{k}=n(n+1)2^{n-1}$$

Answer (score -1):

[image]
I don’t know how to type these sigma function so I posted written one

Comment: Try to post LaTeX edited post

Comment: I appreciate your effort but unfortunately I dont get the third line, also why do you write "implies " when there is no RHS

Comment: Start learning LaTeX.

Comment: I edited it.    Sir

Comment: You can find a tutorial on typing math on this site here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference (Technically, it's "MathJax".) It's worth learning.

Comment: You have to write \sigma when this enclosed with two $ on both sides.